# Using Automapper to Copy Properties from a Dynamic

Tags: .net, dynamic, json.net, automapper, automapper-5

I have a dynamic object (actually, a JObject, from JSON.NET) being built dynamically from JSON.
I want to have its properties copied to an existing object. The properties from the dynamic object should exist in the target object's type, if not, it's ok to have an error.
I am looking at Automapper, latest version, for this. I tried to create a map from JObject to the proper type, but I don't think it'll work because the properties in the JObject are stored in an internal dictionary.
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

If you already have a `JObject`, then you don't really need Automapper to copy the properties from it to your existing target object.  The Json.Net serializer provides a [`Populate()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm) method which will do this.  You can create an extension method to make it easy to call right from the `JObject`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void PopulateObject<T>(this JToken jt, T target)
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Populate(jt.CreateReader(), target);
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to copy the properties you can do this:

```
jObj.PopulateObject<Foo>(existingFoo);
```

Note: if your variable that holds the `JObject` is declared as `dynamic` then you'll have to cast it so the runtime binder can find the extension method:

```
((JObject)jObj).PopulateObject<Foo>(existingFoo);
```

Here is a quick demo to prove the concept: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dhPDCj

If you would still prefer to use Automapper, you can configure it to do this same conversion instead of its usual member-based mapping.  The trick is to use the `ConvertUsing` method when setting up the mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<JObject, Foo>().ConvertUsing((jo, foo) =>
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), foo);
    return foo;
}));
```

Then use this code to copy the properties:

```
Mapper.Map<JObject, Foo>(jObj, existingFoo);
```

Comment: No... I explicitly said I wated to copy tje properties to an *existing* object!

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that detail in your question.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @BrianRogers You had indicated: The Json.Net serializer provides a PopulateObject() method... but really they provide the Populate() method.  Your answer is still clear, but it is a little misleading.

Comment: Actually it looks like newtonsoft have added their own PopulateObject method: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(string value, object target)

Comment: @TimFriesen You're right; I had the wrong method name in the text of the answer; although the code example was correct.  I fixed it and added a link to the documentation.  `JsonSerializer` has `Populate`; `JsonConvert` has `PopulateObject`.  The difference is in the parameters they accept.  The former is what we need here since it accepts a `JsonReader`, which can be created from the `JObject`.  The latter is used when you are starting from a JSON string.