# Automapper Not Mapping JObject To POCO Not Mapping Int

Tags: c#, json.net, automapper, .net-core-2.1

**Example code**

```
    JToken json = JObject.Parse(
        " {\"Url\": \"www.fakeUrl.com\",\"CallId\": 12}");

    var poco = mapper.Map<CallData>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.WriteLine(poco.Url + " " + poco.CallId);
```

***Simple Model***

```
   public class CallData
    {
        public int CallId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output**

> {   "Url": "www.fakeUrl.com",   "CallId": 12 }
>
> www.fakeUrl.com 0

I'm just curious to why Automapper isn't mapping the integer in this JSON object? I know there are alternatives out such as a custom extension for this but I'm wondering why AutoMapper can't do this simple map?

Automapper V7.0.1

Comment: Code seems right. Have you tried using `JObject` instead `JToken`?. Maybe there is something odd with `Json.net`.

Comment: Yes, tried JToken and still nothing, I'm just opening an issue on Automappers GitHub too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Automapper to Copy Properties from a Dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394587/using-automapper-to-copy-properties-from-a-dynamic)

Comment: Thanks @OrelEraki that is useful, however I still feel there is an issue here as Automapper should be able to map this primitive type without the need for extensions. It maps the string just not the integer? I'm looking for answers more than an alternative soltuion

Comment: Combining your code with a custom mapping [it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107415/automapperconverting-json-to-list-of-objects) There seems to be some code out there using TypeConverters http://codingcanvas.com/mapping-json-to-objects-using-automapper/

Comment: I would advice on editing your question to state you have a problem with implementing a workaround to avoid flagging as duplicate.

Comment: How are you initializing `mapper`?

Comment: Nothing special Asherber,       var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<profileName>();
            });

            return config.CreateMapper();

Comment: I initialise it with just the profile containing the logic in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226236/3649914)

Comment: I tried your example, and it event didn't mapped the Url. This is due the nature of JObject which isn't composed of static property types, but it's a dynamic container for JProperties which is not a primitive type, but it's value is inside one of it's inner properties. Thus, AutoMapper can't just guess how to extract it, you should tell it how to do so. Fortunately, Json.Net did an easy way to help you with that, by using CreateReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding a custom mapping. I still believe this to be an issue with the underlining libraries and will investigate further as this simple primitive mapping shouldn't need extensions.

**Mapper**

```
CreateMap<dynamic ,CallData>().ConvertUsing((jo) =>
{
    var callData = new CallData();
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    if(jo != null)
     serializer.Populate((JsonReader) jo.CreateReader(), callData);
    return callData;
});
```

**Usage**

```
var response =_mapper.Map<dynamic, CallData>(_callData);
```

Comment: AM doesn't reference Newtonsoft.Json (and no, json objects are not primitive types). But this support can be easily added outside AM. AM supports directly only built-in types.